# Are Nanoblocks compatible with other building bricks?

Tags: clone-brands, compatibility, 3rd-party

Recently I have found [Nanoblocks](https://web.archive.org/web/20111016214951/http://www.mynanoblock.com/site/), a Japanese brick toy, in American stores. How compatible are these with other building toys? They look to be approximately the same scale as Modulex.

Comment: they sure don't look the right size :P http://www.mynanoblock.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/slide-11.jpg Edit... oh wait that's the "mini" series

Comment: No, that's what I'm asking about. They appear about the same size as Modulex (although I've never used Modulex), and AFOL are a creative bunch - I wouldn't be surprised if someone figured out a way to integrate them with regular LEGO bricks as well.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that the goal of the nanoblock producers is to make "the world’s smallest toy building blocks"<sup>[1](http://www.mynanoblock.com/site/?page_id=2)</sup>.  And they appear to be too small to be compatible with LEGO.  See the following video comparisons of the sizes.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Cobnr8fWTY

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QXGP837-dU

<sub><sub>1. http://www.mynanoblock.com/site/?page_id=2</sub></sub>

Comment: Obviously they aren't going to fit right on top of a LEGO stud. But the question is about generally compatibility - for example, are they compatible with Diablock (for which there are LEGO-compatible adapters)? Are they compatible with Modulex, which is a Lego Group product incompatible with standard LEGO bricks but at the same scale? Are there any LEGO pieces which will serve as a hacky adapter?

Answer (score 4):

I can attest that Nano bloks (left) are **not** the same scale as Modulex (right).[image: Nano blok and Modulex]

Answer (score -3):

[image]
[image]Duplo = compatible with normal Lego even though 2× the size as has hollow stud. Tube of normal 2×2 fits inside. Nano blocks 2×2 being 1/2 size of normal fit with a brick having a hollow stud, e.g. 1 round or 1×1 with holder. But Kawada Nano Blocks don't use tubes, so not fit like this when other makes do.
Guess that Nano Blocks' plastic = 1/2 as thick, could only attach Lego by over hanging a corner with it touching the 2nd stud.
I've just got some 1/2 size bricks, don't know what brand, can attach under Lego ×2 by having 1/10 on 1 side & 2/5 on the other.
Edge of System Lego fits between 2 studs, so can trap between brick & tile.

They also fit end of ×2 Modulex by 2 studs on a corner, if both ends of 2×5 then can join the 2 with nano.
Duplo, need to miss every 3rd to avoid the ribs.

Tenté, thinner walls & bigger stud than System Lego, tight fit, not holding when not reaching the edges.

Photo, arms & legs of Lego, head & torso of Nano Blocks. 2nd is Nano Blocks on Lego 1×2's with 1 stud  (at 90° to each other) & then Modulex on top.